# Can save stream as local file, but when returning it as HttpResponseMessage - always empty file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stream, powerbi-embedded

I want to write export/download functionality for files from external API.
I've created separate Action for it. Using external API I can get stream for that file.
When I am saving that stream to local file, everything is fine, file isn't empty.

```
var exportedFile = await this.GetExportedFile(client, this.ReportId, this.WorkspaceId, export);

// Now you have the exported file stream ready to be used according to your specific needs
// For example, saving the file can be done as follows:
string pathOnDisk = @"D:\Temp\" + export.ReportName + exportedFile.FileSuffix;
                
using (var fileStream = File.Create(pathOnDisk))
{
    await exportedFile.FileStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

But when I return `exportedFile` object that contains in it `stream` and do next:

```
var result = await this._service.ExportReport(reportName, format, CancellationToken.None);

var fileResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    await result.FileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;

    fileResult.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer());
}
            
fileResult.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                                                {
                                                    FileName = $"{reportName}{result.FileSuffix}"
                                                 };

fileResult.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

return fileResult;
```

Exported file is always empty.

Is it problem with stream or with code that try to return that stream as file?

---

Tried as @Nobody suggest to use `ToArray`

```
fileResult.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());
```

the same result.

---

Also tried to use `StreamContent`

```
fileResult.Content = new StreamContent(result.FileStream);
```

still empty file.

But when I'm using `StreamContent` and `MemmoryStream`

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
     await result.FileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
     ms.Position = 0;

     fileResult.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
}
```

in result I got

> {
> "error": "no response from server"
> }

---

Note: from 3rd party API I get stream that is readonly.

Comment: Why are you change position of MemoryStream?

Comment: And are you sure stream is not empty? You can check it invoking ToArray() on MemoryStream on debug and check stream has some non 0 bytes

Comment: @kalit, yes, stream isn't empty. That stream can be successfully be saved into file on local machine, but when returning in response - it is empty

Comment: Please share how `exportedFile.FileStream` is being set up and its type. Also, is this `FileStream` property being read/copied from before being assigned to the `ByteArrayContent`?

Comment: @pfx I'm using PowerBI API to get filestream from dashboard https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to#step-3---getting-the-file Everything as in example... just that `ExportedFile` object go up to API controller that called that service. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

you used GetBuffer() to retrieve the data of the memory stream.
The function you should use is ToArray()
Please read the Remarks of the documentation of these functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer?view=net-6.0

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Position = 0;
    await result.FileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);

    fileResult.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray()); //ToArray() and not GetBuffer()
}
```

Comment: tried this, but still file is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Your "mistake" although it's an obvious one is that you return a status message, but not the actual file itself (which is in it's own also a 200).

You return this:

```
var fileResult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

So you're not sending a file, but a response message. What I'm missing in your code samples is the procedure call itself, but since you use a HttpResonseMessage I will assume it's rather like a normal Controller action. If that is the case you could respond in a different manner:

```
return new FileContentResult(byteArray, mimeType){ FileDownloadName = filename };
```

where byteArray is ofcourse just a byte[], the mimetype could be application/octet-stream (but I suggest you'd actually find the correct mimetype for the browser to act accordingly) and the filename is the filename you want the file to be named.

So, if you were to stitch above and my comment together you'd get this:

```
var exportedFile = await this.GetExportedFile(client, this.ReportId, this.WorkspaceId, export);

// Now you have the exported file stream ready to be used according to your specific needs
// For example, saving the file can be done as follows:
string pathOnDisk = @"D:\Temp\" + export.ReportName + exportedFile.FileSuffix;
                
using (var fileStream = File.Create(pathOnDisk))
{
    await exportedFile.FileStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}

return new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathOnDisk), "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = export.ReportName + exportedFile.FileSuffix };
```

I suggest to try it, since you still report a 200 (and not a fileresult)

Comment: no, it's ApiController... but I tried your advice (using swagger) and in result I just get 200 response with html page

Comment: what html page?

Comment: my layout without any content

Comment: I suggest to try added code (as method)